# How to click a link on a webpage on Chrome using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, tags

I am trying to use Excel to download a CSV file from a webpage.

The webpage is a Kibana dashboard, within the dashboard there is a link which will start a download once clicked.

I would like to write an Excel macro to click this link (and extract the data from the downloaded CSV file).

I've got as far as opening Chrome on the correct webpage. How do I select the link?

```vb
Sub scraping_web()

Dim driver As New WebDriver
driver.Start "chrome"

' Navigate to a webpage
driver.Get "https://atlas-kibana.corp.amazon.com/goto/8035c5711eb0a8673178103a422c208c"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
' Find all 'a' tags on the webpage
Dim links As WebElements
Set links = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//a")

' Loop through each 'a' tag and print its text
Dim link As WebElement
For Each link In links
    Debug.Print link.Text
Next link

' Close the browser window
driver.Quit
End Sub
```

[image]